# Visual Studio Voca Not Running Code with Conda Environment (remote connection to AWS)

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, anaconda

I am using VSCode to connect to connect my AWS EC2 instance. I've been using since months without any issues. I am also using conda environments. I am on Windows locally but connecting to Ubuntu machine.

Today I was debugging my code. I use F5 key to start debugging. Suddenly it stopped working. When I press F5 (or try to run the code in any way), I see the buttons for stopping code etc. appear for like half a second, then disappears, and nothing else happens. It worked 1 second ago without any issues, now it is not working. I tried uninstalling VSCode, removing appdata files for VSCode, removing extensions and reinstalling. None of that worked.

If I don't select a conda environment, it works without issues. But I need to use environments for reasons.

I also got an error the first time this happened:

> ~/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nms/cpu_nms.pyx
> (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file'vscode-remote: ... (points
> to same file) )

I tried different environments and also tried my other laptop as my local machine. None of that worked.

How can I solve the issue?